# Node JS array formation

Tags: javascript, mysql, arrays, node.js, api

I am pulling data from mysql and my node js api is responding the complete row as an array . but the front end developer needs the first column out of the main array .

Current api response :

```
[{
  column1 :data,
  column2 :data,
  column3 :data
}]
```

Front end developer needs :

```
[{ column 1 : data },
 { column2 : data, column3 : data }]
```

I am sending the data back as res.send(rows) currently.

Believe I need to use a for condition.

Can someone help?

Comment: this is not al valid JSON format: [
{ column 1 : data , nestedobj:
          {column2 : data,
           column3 : data
          }
}
]
I think your problem your not valid format.

Comment: This makes no sense to me. The front end guy can easily just iterate over the rows and then pull the first column from each row.  You’re sending what should be considered a fairly standard response.

Comment: also, how do you plan to send multiple rows in the `frontend format` ? Arrays within an array ?

Comment: he wants multiple rows in different array . Pushing it back to consume the standart JSON format.

Answer (score -1):

OK, the first code here was a joke

This should work fine

```js
const indata = [{
  column1 :'data1',
  column2 :'data2',
  column3 :'data3'
},{
  column1 :'data4',
  column2 :'data5',
  column3 :'data6'
}];
const outdata = [].concat(...indata.map(item => Object.entries(item).map(([key, data]) => ({[key]: data}))));
console.log(outdata);
```

Comment: Thanks. Will this handle multiple rows also ?

Comment: this was a joke

Comment: @Ragu - sorry about that, I was messing around, the code you originally saw was complete garbage - I'v fixed the code now